# I want to put a Youtube URL in a HTML5 video tag and play it

Tags: youtube, html5-video, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

```
<video muted autoplay playinline loop controls preload="metadata" src="https://www.youtube.com/××××××"></video>
```

I would like to put a Youtube URL in a HTML5 video tag and play it.

When I use the above code, I get a black screen and the video does not play.

Is there a better way to do this?

I want to use AR.js to play a video using AR technology, but if I put the Yotube embed code in place of the video tag, it will not play, and if I put the youtube URL inside the video tag as shown above, it will not play.

Comment: The `<video>` tag only loads video files. You cannot use URL of a web page (since it is html text) as video file. If you need the video file maybe download it first. Try getting it via a [Youtube Video Downloader Site](https://getvideo.at/en/).